# Salesforce Marketing Cloud API - 596 Service Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm getting a "596 Service Not Found" error when using the Salesforce Marketing Cloud API and I need help with this. I couldn't solve my problem and I need your help.

How can I send a query to the API with the following information?

```
SalesforceAccessToken = "fkc5pm4kgfnx55gfcggk6zx3"
SalesforceAppId = "e5a97149-c635-498a-b264-663a0f4b2dd2"
SalesforceMarketingCloudServerUrl = "https://mcfk02nd3k8q7w75g9yxxcc6yj20.device.marketingcloudapis.com/"
SalesforceMidKey = "100004444"
```

I'm encountering a "596 Service Not Found" error while using the Salesforce Marketing Cloud API, and I need assistance in resolving this issue. I haven't been able to solve this problem on my own, and I'm seeking help to understand what might be causing this error.

Comment: Are you sure the "your-endpoint" is the actual endpoint? You should change it with your actual endpoint